# how to connect to wi fi in dell vostro 2420?

Tags: wireless

i am not able to connect to the wi-fi in my area please help me out how to connect to the wi-fi from the starting. i have recently bought my new laptop DELL VOSTRO 2420. how to connect wi-fi to this???

Answer (score 0):

First, install the prerequisites by opening a terminal and pasting, one line at a time:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers$(uname -r | grep -Po "\-[a-z].*")
sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms
```

Please download the appropriate DEB file from Dropbox here:

[32-bit/i386](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n76dcsdtayvp0wm/wireless-bcm43142-dkms-6.20.55.19_i386.deb)

[64-bit/amd64](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jerkl6uqal5ylv3/wireless-bcm43142-dkms-6.20.55.19_amd64.deb)

Open a terminal, and install it with `sudo dpkg -i`.

Hopefully it works!

Edit: 12.04 now has an updated `bcmwl-kernel-source` package that reportedly supports BCM43142.